# sqldf in R compare two data.frames and store output

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, lapply, sqldf

So, I have around 500 .txt data files, they all contain 8 columns. Each datafile has in each column the same a mount of values (rows). If you compare the datafile1 and datafile2 then they mostly have different amount of rows, but they have some of those row values are the same and some are not.
I want to find all values, which are different between datafile1 and datafile1+1= datafile2, which I have allready solved with sqldf.

first I load all the files using lapply

`list_of_files <- list.files(path = ".", recursive = TRUE, pattern = "\\.txt$",`
`full.names =TRUE)`

`DT <- lapply(list_of_files, read.table)`

load all datafiles, so that the first datafile can be selected with DT[[1]] and the second with DT[[1+1]], which would be suitable for a loop.

For DT, I only want to compare column V4 and V5 of each datafile and I thought I could loop that with DT[[i]] and DT[[i+1]], but I could not get it to work. Below I show what worked for DT[[1]] and DT[[2]]. First I created to data.frames, which contained both columns V4 and V5 of the respective data.frames:

`dt1<-data.frame(DT[[1]]$V4,DT[[1]]$V5)`

`dt2<-data.frame(DT[[1+1]]$V4,DT[[1+1]]$V5)`

Here I select only the values with differ between dt1 and dt2:

`df<-sqldf('SELECT * FROM dt1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM dt2')`

I would like to loop the df action over all 500 datafiles DT[[i]] DT[[i+1]]  store all df values in a data.frame

Maybe somebody has an idea how to loop that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function :

```
get_data<- function(dt1, dt2) sqldf('SELECT * FROM dt1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM dt2')
```

Now use `Map` to apply this function to loop and apply it to every `DT[i]` and `DT[i+1]`

```
result <- Map(get_data, DT[-length(DT)], DT[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot works great! I knew somebody will know it!
The result output at the moment contains in your solution all the columns V1 to V8. If you want only certain columns then you can modify the function, as shown below:

`rm(list=ls())`

`library(sqldf)`

`setwd("Path_to_txt-files")`

`list_of_files <- list.files(path = ".", recursive = TRUE,pattern = "\\.txt$",full.names = TRUE)`

`DT <- lapply(list_of_files, read.table)`

`dt1<-data.frame(DT[[25]]$V4,DT[[25]]$V5)`

`dt2<-data.frame(DT[[25+1]]$V4,DT[[25+1]]$V5)`

#`df<-sqldf('SELECT * FROM dt1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM dt2')` not used if you want to loop it over several files

result output will contain only column V4 and V5:

`get_data<- function(dt1, dt2) sqldf('SELECT V4,V5 FROM dt1 EXCEPT SELECT V4,V5 FROM dt2')`

`result <- Map(get_data, DT[-length(DT)], DT[-1])`

`result`